# I am attempting to create a php search bar that directs to larger search engines. It isn't working and I don't understand how to solve it.

Tags: php, search

webdevprocess.html 
[This page is used solely for the search bar at the bottom of the page. Any search term can be entered and then a search engine can be selected from the drop down menu.]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Web Development Process</title>
<meta name="Web Development Process" content="Simple Responsive Template is a template for responsive web design. Mobile first, responsive grid layout, toggle menu, navigation bar with unlimited drop downs, responsive slideshow">
<meta name="keywords" content="">

<!-- Mobile viewport -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico"  type="image/x-icon">
<!-- CSS-->
<!-- Google web fonts. You can get your own bundle at http://www.google.com/fonts. Don't forget to update the CSS accordingly!-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif|Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/flexslider/flexslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic-style.css">
<!-- end CSS-->
<!-- JS-->
<script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mypiechart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<!-- end JS-->
</head>
<body>

<body id="home">
<!-- header area -->
    <header class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div id="banner">        
            <div id="logo"><a href="webdevprocess.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo"></a></div> 
        </div>
        <!-- main navigation -->
        <nav id="topnav" role="navigation">
          <div class="menu-toggle">Menu</div>  
          <ul class="srt-menu" id="menu-main-navigation">
              <li class="current"><a href="webdevprocess.html">Home page</a></li>
             <!-- <li><a href="basic-internal.html">Internal page demo</a></li> -->
              <li><a href="clientserver.html">Client/Server Technology</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li>
                          <a href="clienserver.html">Client/Server Technology</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="domainnames.html">Domain Names and Hosting</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">JavaScript Pages</a>
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="webdevprocess.html">Web Development Process</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">PHP Pages</a>
              </li> 
          </ul>     
        </nav><!-- end main navigation -->

    </header><!-- end header -->
<!-- main content area -->   
<div id="main" class="wrapper">
<!-- content area -->    
    <section id="content" class="wide-content">
      <div class="row"> 
      <h1>What Is The Web Development Process?</h1>
      <p>A web development process,or web design and development process, is a systematic process or methodology, used tp desgn and build web sites. Just as planing goes into the design 
      of cars, buildings, or homes, so too is the planning and design and development process required for web sites. A good process helps ensure customer requirements are delivered in a quality
      , timely and cos-effective manner.</p>
      <h1>SDLC and Project Management</h1>
      <p>The web design and development process can be thought of as a type of software development life cycle (SDLC) and project management methodology. The waterfall model depicted 
      below is a long-standing, traditional SDLC that is characterized by sequential steps. Agile is a newer method that is intended to more quickly respond to changing customer and
      product requirements using an incremental process with frequent releases and customer feedback.</p>
      <h3>Traditional Waterfall SDLC Methodology (PNG image)</h3>
      <p><img src="waterfall.png" alt="Waterfall SDLC"></p>
      <p>Source: WikiPedia</p>
      <h3>Agile Methodology (GIF image)</h3>
      <p><img src="images/agile.png" alt="Agile Methodology"></p>
      <h3>Web Development Phases (HTML/JavaScript image)</h3>
      <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 450px; width: 95%;"></div>
      <script>
window.onload = function() {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title: {
        text: "Web Development Process"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "pie",
        startAngle: 240,
        yValueFormatString: "##0.00\"%\"",
        indexLabel: "{label} {y}",
        dataPoints: [
            {y: 20.00 , label: "Testing"},
            {y: 10.00, label: "Promotion"},
            {y: 25.00, label: "Analysis"},
            {y: 20.00, label: "Design"},
            {y: 25.00, label: "Construction"}
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
<br> 
<form action="search.php" method="get">
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Search Sites</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Site to Search:</td>
<td>
<select name="site">
<option value="google">Google Web
<option value="googlei">Google Images
<option value="duck">DuckDuckGo
<option value="wiki">WikiPedia
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Search term(s):</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="terms" size="25" maxlength="25">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class-"centercell">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br>
      </div><!-- end row -->
    </section><!-- end content area -->   
  </div><!-- #end div #main .wrapper -->
<!-- footer area -->    
<footer>
    <div id="colophon" class="wrapper clearfix">
        Author: Janae Roland
    </div>
<!--You can NOT remove this attribution statement from any page, unless you get the permission from prowebdesign.ro--><div id="attribution" class="wrapper clearfix" style="color:#666; font-size:11px;">Site built with <a href="http://www.prowebdesign.ro/simple-responsive-template/" target="_blank" title="Simple Responsive Template is a free software by www.prowebdesign.ro" style="color:#777;">Simple Responsive Template</a> by <a href="http://www.prowebdesign.ro/" target="_blank" title="www.prowebdesign.ro" style="color:#777;">Prowebdesign.ro</a></div><!--end attribution-->

</footer><!-- #end footer area --> 
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
<script defer src="js/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<!-- fire ups - read this file!  -->   
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

search.php 
[This program is supposed to send the search terms entered to large search engines (google,google images,duck duck go,wikipedia) but I am receiving a syntax error, "
Notice: Use of undefined constant FIlTER_SANITIZE_STRING - assumed 'FIlTER_SANITIZE_STRING' in /home/jsroland/public_html/search.php on line 13
Warning: filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in /home/jsroland/public_html/search.php on line 13"]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Rock,Paper,Scissors">
<meta name="description" content="A function that sends data to large search engines,through the WebDev search bar.">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$site = substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'site', FIlTER_SANITIZE_STRING),0,8);
$terms = substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'terms', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),0,25);
if ($site == "google")
    header('Location: http://www.google.com/#g=' . $terms);
else if ($site == "googlei")
    header('Location: http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&g=' . $terms);
else if ($site == "duck")
    header('Location: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=&ia=web' . $terms);
else if ($site == "wiki")
    header('Location: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' . $terms);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would just like to add a little clarity to the situation. If I seem like I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm a student, I'm really new to anything past html and css and I'm just learning and trying to figure this out one day at a time. If you can please bear with me I'd be so grateful. Any help is so greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got a typo, it should be `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` (all caps) in `$site = substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'site', FIlTER_SANITIZE_STRING),0,8);`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. For some reason the php validators didn't catch that.

Comment: I have a small residual problem. When using a test search term, the only search engine that completely follows through with bringing up relative information about the term. It simply goes to the search engine's "home page" instead of searching the term. Is there something wrong with my addresses? If anyone can help,it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure, it might be the wrong address issue. Which engine is not working? I assume there might be a problem with DuckDuckGo because you're passing an empty query string `...?q=&...`. It must be `'https://duckduckgo.com/?ia=web&q='`.

Comment: The google engine,google image engine,and duck duck go engines aren't working. I didn't really understand how to get the query to operate.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal correct urls for search engines would be as follows:

- for general Google search: `https://www.google.com/search?q='<search
  terms>'`,
- for Google image search:
  `https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q='<search terms>'`,
- for
  DuckDuckGo: `https://duckduckgo.com/?ia=web&q='<search terms>'`,
- for
  Wikipedia: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/<search terms>`.

where `<search terms>` are the terms to search for.

Please also mind quotation marks in the first three cases. The final code would look something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Rock,Paper,Scissors">
        <meta name="description" content="A function that sends data to large search engines,through the WebDev search bar.">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $site = substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'site', FIlTER_SANITIZE_STRING),0,8);
        $terms = substr(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'terms', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),0,25);
        if ($site == "google")
            header("Location: https://www.google.com/search?q='$terms'");
        else if ($site == "googlei")
            header("https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q='$terms'");
        else if ($site == "duck")
            header("Location: https://duckduckgo.com/?ia=web&q='$terms'");
        else if ($site == "wiki")
            header("Location: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/$terms");

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```